# how to filter posts by multiple categories using AND

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I developed a WordPress website now I'm using wp rest API v2 to get posts and I'm going to filter posts by multi categories, for example I want to get a post that is in categories mobile AND tech both.
this URL get posts in category mobile OR category tech 
 `filter[category_name]=mobile/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=mobile&filter[category_name]=tech`
but I want to get posts using filter by AND (not OR)
what's the solution

Comment: Have you found the solution?